# Canvas, как сделать анимацию линии из массива точек?

Tags: javascript, анимация, canvas

Есть массив точек.
Мне нужно сделать анимацию рисования линии.
Как это можно реализовать ?
Вот пример моего кода:

https://jsfiddle.net/drakoice/v6r75uoq/2/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('c1');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var timer;

let oneLineX = [0,50,75,100,140,150,200,280,300,320,350];
let oneLineY = [100,90,100,110,100,90,100,100,90,100,100];

function drawLine1(){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  ctx.lineWidth = '4';
  ctx.moveTo(oneLineX[0],oneLineY[0]);
  for(var i=1; i<10;i++){
    ctx.lineTo(oneLineX[i],oneLineY[i]);
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
  }
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}

drawLine1();
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('c1');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var timer;

let oneLineX = [0,50,75,100,140,150,200,280,300,320,350];
let oneLineY = [100,90,100,110,100,90,100,100,90,100,100];

function drawLine1(){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  ctx.lineWidth = '4';
  ctx.moveTo(oneLineX[0],oneLineY[0]);
  for(var i=1; i<10;i++){
    ctx.lineTo(oneLineX[i],oneLineY[i]);
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
  }
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}

drawLine1();
```

```css
#c1 {
 width: 400px;
 height: 200px;
 border: 3px solid black;
 margin: 40px;
 background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="js.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="c1" width="400" height="200"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Какую именно анимацию рисования нужно реализовать - не понятно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;
const coords = [
  { x: 0, y: 100 },
  { x: 50, y: 90 },
  { x: 75, y: 100 },
  { x: 100, y: 110 },
  { x: 140, y: 100 },
  { x: 150, y: 90 },
  { x: 200, y: 100 },
  { x: 280, y: 100 },
  { x: 300, y: 90 },
  { x: 320, y: 100 },
  { x: 350, y: 100 },
];
let index = 0;
const step = 2;

lastPosition = {
  x: coords[0].x,
  y: coords[0].y
};
function draw() {
  if (index + 2 > coords.length) return;
  const startPoint = lastPosition;
  const endPoint = coords[index+1];
  const arrPoints = [startPoint.x, startPoint.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y];
  const length = getLengthLine(...arrPoints);
  const next = getNextPoint(length, step, ...arrPoints);
  arrPoints[2] = next.x;
  arrPoints[3] = next.y;
  drawLine(...arrPoints);
  lastPosition.x = next.x;
  lastPosition.y = next.y;
  if (Math.round(next.x) >= endPoint.x && Math.round(next.y) >= endPoint.y ) index++;
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function getLengthLine(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2) + Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2));
}
function getNextPoint(len, step, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  const k = step / len;
  const x = x1 + (x2 - x1) * k;
  const y = y1 + (y2 - y1) * k;
  return { x, y };
};

function drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 4;
  ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
  ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

И все же одной линией лучше:

```js
let ctx = c1.getContext('2d');
let oneLineX = [0,50,75,100,140,150,200,280,300,320,350];
let oneLineY = [100,90,100,110,100,90,100,100,90,100,100];
let dur = 2000;
let total = 0;
for(var i = 1; i < oneLineX.length; i++) 
  total += len(i);
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.lineWidth = '4';
requestAnimationFrame(drawLine1);

function len(i) {
  let dx = oneLineX[i] - oneLineX[i-1];
  let dy = oneLineY[i] - oneLineY[i-1];
  return Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
}

function drawLine1(t) {
  dur > t && requestAnimationFrame(drawLine1);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 200)
  ctx.beginPath();
  t = t/dur*total;
  ctx.moveTo(oneLineX[0], oneLineY[0]);
  for (var i = 1; i < oneLineX.length; i++) {
    let l = len(i);
    if (t < l) {
      ctx.lineTo(oneLineX[i-1] + (oneLineX[i] - oneLineX[i-1])*t/l,
                 oneLineY[i-1] + (oneLineY[i] - oneLineY[i-1])*t/l);
      break;           
    }
    t -= l;
    ctx.lineTo(oneLineX[i], oneLineY[i]);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
#c1 {
  border: solid;
  background: linear-gradient(#0000 49px, #000 50px), 
              linear-gradient(to left, #0000 49px, #000 50px);
  background-size: 50px 50px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c1" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: @Дмытрык я не понял что не понятно..

Comment: @Дмытрык у меня каждый кадр рисуются все точки с начала, но в целом можно каждый раз дорисовывать лишь дельту, без очистки, правда визуально могут быть артефакты

Comment: @StrangerintheQ классное решение! А решение с d3 не хочешь добавить? Можно было бы и циферки добавить к координатной сетке и.... Шапка очень идёт твоему образу Евгения Леонова!